# Boundedness of a linear operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

How can I prove that a linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ that satisfies
$$ \langle x,Ay\rangle= \langle y,Ax\rangle$$
for all $x,y\in H$ is bounded (i.e., $\|Ax\|\leq c\|x\| $ for some constant $c>0$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_{x}:y\rightarrow\left<y,Ax\right>$, then $B_{x}$ is a linear operator (beware that one shouldn't take $\left<Ax,y\right>$ because then it is conjugate linear, not linear), and $|B_{x}(y)|=\left|\left<y,Ax\right>\right|=\left|\left<x,Ay\right>\right|\leq\|x\|\|Ay\|$.

For fixed $y$, for all $x$ with $\|x\|\leq 1$, we have $|B_{x}(y)|\leq\|Ay\|$, so 
\begin{align*}
\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|B_{x}(y)|\leq\|Ay\|<\infty.
\end{align*}
By Uniform Boundedness Principle we have 
\begin{align*}
\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|B_{x}\|<\infty,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|A\|=\sup\{\left|\left<y,Ax\right>\right|: \|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1\}=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|B_{x}\|<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you.I'll accept you answer. However, I don't want to solve this problem using Closed Graph Theorem. (I know I should've specified it in the question) I want to use the equivalence of continuity and boundedness to prove that $A$ is bounded? Do you know how to do it that way?

Comment: I have one formula $\|A\|=\sup\{\left|\left<Ax,y\right>\right|: \|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1\}$ and have played that for about fifteen minutes, but I don't get anything useful.

Comment: I have an idea. Let $B_x(.):=\langle Ax,. \rangle$ for a fixed $x$. Then $\|B_x\|= \sup_{\|y\|=1} | \langle Ax, y \rangle | \leq \sup_{\|y\|=1} \| Ax \| \|y\| = \|Ax\| < \infty$. So, $B_x$ is bounded.  Can we then somehow conclude that $A$ is also bounded?

Comment: Let's see my new answer now, I underestimated the difficulty of this question, sorry.

Comment: What is Uniform Boundedness Theorem?

Comment: Look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle).

Comment: It really is about uniform boundedness.

Comment: The wikipedia page you sent me, the $F$ set that you're taking here is $F:=\{B_x|\|x\|\leq 1 \}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: May I suggest you change the answer a bit so it becomes clearer for the readers?

Comment: Like what things should I add?

Comment: Why is $\|A\|=\sup\{\left|\left<y,Ax\right>\right|: \|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1\}$?

Comment: We have $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|Ax\|$. But by Riesz Representation Theorem we know that $\|Ax\|=\sup_{\|y\|\leq 1}\left|\left<y,Ax\right>\right|$.